# I want to create a button along my prepend list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently started JQuery and I need to create a list using the datepicker JQuery function. The problem starts with my prepend because I have to prepend the date I get from the datepicker, the event AND a new button to ERASE whatever's in that line (so the button must be prepended along the list item). I'm having some trouble with this part.

This is the code I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display month &amp; year menus</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        });
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#bta', '#apagar', function () {

        if ($('#datepicker').val() != '' && $('#evento').val() != '' ) {
            $('#caixa').prepend('<p>' + $('#datepicker').val() + $('#evento').val() + $('<input type="button" id="apagar" value="apagar" />') + '</p>');
            $('input').val('');
        }

    });

      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box">
            Lista de Tarefas:
            <br><br>
            Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> &nbsp; &nbsp;

            Event: <input type="text" id="evento">    <button id="bta" class="bta">+</button>

            <div id="caixa">  </div>
            </body>
        </div>

</html>
```

I'm pretty sure this is probably very simple but I've only now started looking around and everything I try to search is either overly complex or doesn't resolve my issue... of course my inability to implement the solutions I find might be very well a problem too.

[This is to help visualize my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpREt.png)

Comment: `'<p>' + $('#datepicker').val() + $('#evento').val() + $('<input type="button" id="apagar" value="apagar" />') + '</p>'` to `'<p>' + $('#datepicker').val() + $('#evento').val() + '<input type="button" id="apagar" value="apagar" /></p>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.prepend` takes argument that are htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery elements. You choose a htmlString, but are adding a jQuery object to this string. This will obviously not work.

What do we actually want? Well, we want to create a `<p>` tag, then append the datepicker value, the event value and then the button.

```
var $p = $("<p></p>");
$p.append($('#datepicker').val(), $('#evento').val(), $('<input type="button" id="apagar" value="apagar" />'));
$('#caixa').prepend($p);
```

Alternatively, skip the step where you turn a string into a jquery object, back into a string.

```
$('#caixa').prepend('<p>' + $('#datepicker').val() + $('#evento').val() + '<input type="button" id="apagar" value="apagar" /></p>');
```